# How does Firebug work from the architecture?

Tags: firebug

I use Firebug for tracking http and debugging etc and I trust Firebug because of its stable. But I want to know how Firebug works from the backend such as how it tracks http. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for it could help. Do you expect to get a detailed architecture review of a piece of code here? I doubt that will happen.

Comment: Thanks. just want to know high level architecture and what it is different from other debug tools such as IE developer tool.